# A priori estimate for degenerate elliptic equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, parabolic-pde

Consider the following degenerate elliptic equation:
$$
\lambda u(x,y)-\Delta_yu(x,y)-y\nabla_x u(x,y)-b(y)\nabla_xu(x,y)=f(y), 
$$
where $b,f\in C_0^\infty$. Can we prove a priori estimate of the form
$$
\|u\|_\infty\leq C\|f\|_{L^p(R^{2d})} ???
$$

Comment: What about $\lambda=1,b=f=0$?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. The case $b=0$ is possible. In this case, the operator is the Kinetic operator, which has been well studied. But for general $b$, I don't known how to solve it.

Comment: I don't know much about the tools use in Pde, maybe consider the classical ellipitic estimate?

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I will try the simplier case that $b$ is independent of $x$.

Comment: I can look for the book in pde, but it might take some time.